# Should I use two Postgres databases for Django on Heroku - dev & prod?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm quite new to Django.
I'm building a Django app and want to deploy it to Heroku with Postgres database.
I already installed a Postgres app on Heroku, and have my credentials.

Should I have two databases - one Postgres database with its own settings locally for dev, and one that is on Heroku?

The app is quite simple, so I don't necessarily need two databases, but maybe it is needed for deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how simple the app is - NEVER mix dev and prod databases.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple - I'll use sqlite for dev environment, and postgres for prod - and which would be deployed to Heroku.

Heroku doesn't allow to use sqlite.